# SFMCSDK Mobile push SDK iOS crashes with the exception: com.salesforce.security.keychainException

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios, push-notification

We are seeing a crash on Crashlytics after upgrading marketing cloud SDK to  8.0.8 and SFMCSDK version 1.0.0 in the live version of app. Many users are affected.

> com.salesforce.security.keychainException
> setObject:forKey:: Error saving value to the keychain: errSecInteractionNotAllowed.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when a device is setup with FaceId or Passcode based authentication. If an application (with MarketingCloudSDK integrated) accesses the Keychain when the device is in a locked state, the SDK encounters an exception because of the iOS Data Protection mode.

To fix this, upgrade to MarketingCloudSDK version - 8.0.8 and SFMCSDK version - 1.0.6

With the latest changes, you can now leverage `SFMCSdk.setKeychainAccessErrorsAreFatal(errorsAreFatal: false)` to ensure that these errors are logged, but do not crash the application.

Comment: Thanks Ethan ! I was able to resolve the issue with this.